# Is there a onRightMouseDown an Up Hostlistener in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I´m working on directive that listens to mouse events and only found the **contextmenu event** that works like the **click event** only for the right side.

But I need to know how to get an event if the **right mouse button** is **pressed and released**

Comment: Doesn't contextmenu event work for you?

Comment: Context menu only works when I want to get an click event. But I want to get a mousdown and mouseup event for the right button

Answer (score 1):

To know what mouse button is pressed, you can use the [MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) property.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.

Comment: I thought that there will be an angular solution but they can not catch everything.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the **mousedown event** happens for both buttons an there is a **button property** of the MouseEvent that tells you the number of it.

If it 2 it´s the right button